# Present Main View Controller Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm having some issues when presenting the main view controller (with stock ViewController.m/h files)from an InitialViewController I've created as Launcher.

I want to perform some animation in InitialViewController and then present the home view controller (which is the main, the one you find when you create a blank project).

Here's the code I came up with:

```
-(InitialViewController)

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self CommittAnimation];
    [self performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}




-(void)show
{
    ViewController*home=[ViewController alloc]init;
    [self presentViewController:home animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I haven't shown CommitAnimation because it is not relevant to the problem.

It says me - Unknown type name "ViewController", did you mean UIViewController? -

How can I present my view?  Even performSegue after certain NSTimer value doesn't work.

Comment: do you have a class named VIewController ?

Comment: Yes, it is the default class

Comment: pls post the complete code. The code you posted wont compile.

Comment: Unrelated, you shouldn't be initiating any animations/transitions in `viewDidLoad`. Those should be deferred until `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Ok, I could use ViewWillAppear/DidAppear but remains the fact that I can't switch to ViewController (by the way, its title is "Start", whereas InitialViewController class refers to "Launch" view

Comment: Well, that's all the code I use to skip from Launch view to Start view (InitialViewController---->ViewController)

Comment: `-(InitialViewController)` followed by `- (void)viewDidLoad {` really compiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to perform the animation in your home view controller itself. Just add all your animation elements under one single view and then hide that view when the animation is complete. That ways you wont have to perform segues.

Also, for the error - "Unknown type name "ViewController", did you mean UIViewController? -" 
Did you import "ViewController.h" in your Initial view controller class file?

Comment: No, I didn't. I've found that the import header was missing and i easily fixed all my problems.  What a fool i've been!      Thank you ;)